# Why my implicit conversion function doesn't work?

Tags: c++, casting, implicit

I have a wrapper class and I want to modify the data and convert it back to its original type.

```
class A
{
public:
    A ( unsigned __int64 _a ) : a (_a)
    {
    }
    operator unsigned __int64 () const
    {
        return a;
    }
    unsigned __int64 a;
};
```

I want the object of this class to implicitly convert back to `unsigned __int64`, but it failed.

Say,

```
 A a( 0x100ull );
 unsigned __int64 b = (a >> 16);  // Error
```

Compiler gives C2678 error, no operator found or there is no acceptable conversion. 
It seems this function `operator unsigned __int64 () const` doesn't work.

---

To be more specific, compiler says `there is no acceptable conversion`. I cannot accept the complain, because I have already given a good one. Can someone legitimize it?

Comment: What is an ___int64?  Is that something you've locally defined?

Comment: What compiler ar you using? This compiles fine with VC++2010 - i.e. the implicit conversion to unsigned __int64 is performed.

Comment: @sashang, I actually, simplified my example, now it's the actual one. I was using vs2005

Comment: @Dai: the example works for me with VS 2005 SP1 (specifically compiler version 14.00.50727.762).  Maybe try a later version of Visual Studio (the Express versions are free) or apply SP1 to see if that makes a difference (if you don't already have SP1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you haven't created an `operator>>` overload for your class that takes an integer and does something with it.

I'm guessing you're trying to do a right shift on your int, but I'm not sure that overloading your `operator>>` is a good idea for that, as these operators in a context like that, are normally used for streaming.  It might confuse a reader or maintainer of your code afterwards.

[See here for more info on operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Perhaps rethink your implementation strategy?

Comment: But the OP is presumably expecting the compiler to implicitly call the cast operator here?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But, why compiler didn't convert a to `unsigned ___int64`

Comment: @Oli: do you suggest that `operator>>` should be implemented to cast? I'm not sure what you're trying to suggest?

Comment: Try adding an explicit conversion, `__int64(a) >> 16`.

Comment: @Dai: because your A isn't a `unsigned ___int64`, it's a type of itself, which, because of it's ctor, can implicitly convert to a `unsigned ___int64`, that doesn't however mean it also behaves as one, it just stores it in the member of the class.

Comment: @Dai: I'm not sure now, it should be... does it work if you just change the type to `int`?

Comment: You cannot implicitly cast an object to an int.  (Unless there's some weird C++ magic that I'm not aware of.)

Comment: @Corbin: I defined an operator to perform the cast and it was used implicitly. See here: http://ideone.com/oPxyJ.

Comment: @Dai: What compiler are you using?  The implicit conversion in your code (for the shift operation) works fine for me with MSVC 16 (VS 2010) and  GCC/MinGW 4.5.1.

Comment: @sashang: Apparently I should google before speaking x.x.  I had always assumed that the () operator was used to call something like a() (where a is some object).  Never knew that it's the cast operator.  Learned something today.  (And learned I should check before posting next time :p)

Comment: @Corbin : You're thinking of `SomeType operator()`; he has `operator SomeType()` -- two entirely different operators.